# Is there a name for the type of commonly said phrases that is said in a mocking, yet in a funny way?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

There are some phrases that everybody knows, and are said in a humorous/mocking way like:

- Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell
- Dear diary...

Or Russian have this phrase about their failed attempts of learning English, this being the only thing they remember:

- "London is the capital of Great Britain"

Eddie Izzard in one of his comedy shows shares his French learning experiences, remembering this line. Google seems to agree that it is a popular phrase.

- "Le chat est sur la chaise"

So is there a name of this type of common "knowledge" phrases that are so overused that they are somewhat funny, but not just called "memes"?

Comment: I'm having problems trying to equate "Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell" with "_Le chat est sur la chaise_" as commonly used phrases indicating the only thing some people remember from long-forgotten language lessons.

Comment: Those which are statements of obvious facts are truisms / banalities / clichés / commonplaces. Those which give obvious advice are platitudes / bromides. These have been covered before. Only words actually addressing the 'stock phrases learned by early-learners' requirement would be on-topic.

Comment: I regret I am distracted from this discussion because my postillion has been struck by lightning.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of weeks it has come to me that *old chestnut* may often meet your specification.

> = a subject, idea, or joke that has been discussed or repeated so often that it is not funny any more
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/old-chestnut)

> = A stale joke, story, or saying, as in Dad keeps on telling that old chestnut about how many psychiatrists it takes to change a light bulb. This expression comes from William Dimond's play, The Broken Sword (1816), in which one character keeps repeating the same stories, one of them about a cork tree, and is interrupted each time by another character who says “Chestnut, you mean . . . I have heard you tell the joke twenty-seven times and I am sure it was a chestnut.”
>
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/old-chestnut)